# How to delete attributes under <p> tag in html with regular expression or other ways in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I use this code to keep `<p>` and `<br>` tag in string.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mystring = 'aaa<p>Radio and<BR> television.<br></p><p align="right">very<br/> popular in the world today.</p><p class="myclass">Millions of people watch TV. </p><p>That’s because a radio is very small <span style=":_black;">98.2%</span></p><p>and it‘s easy to carry. <span style=":_black;">haha100%</span></p>bb'
soup = BeautifulSoup(mystring,'html.parser')
for e in soup.find_all():
    if e.name not in ['p','br']:
        e.unwrap()
print(str(soup))
```

The result is:

```
aaa<p>Radio and<br/> television.<br/></p><p align="right">very<br> popular in the world today.</br></p><p class="myclass">Millions of people watch TV. </p><p>That’s because a radio is very small 98.2%</p><p>and it‘s easy to carry. haha100%</p>bb
```

But I found that there are some attributes under the `<p>` tag.
For example, align and class.
In fact,I want to delete `align="right"` and `class="myclass"` and other attributes in `<p>` tag,just keep `<p>` tag.

I want this result:

```
aaa<p>Radio and<br/> television.<br/></p><p>very<br> popular in the world today.</br></p><p>Millions of people watch TV. </p><p>That’s because a radio is very small 98.2%</p><p>and it‘s easy to carry. haha100%</p>bb
```

I want to delete the attributes under the `<p>` tag.

How to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you mean by:

```
for e in soup.find_all():
    if e.name not in ['p','br']:
        e.unwrap()
    else:
        e.attrs={}
print(str(soup))
```